# Is there a difference between the 'Use Any Api Client' and 'API Enabled' permission for Profiles?

Tags: api, permissions, profile, custom-profile

I noticed the 'Use Any Api Client' permission only available if 'API Client Whitelisting' is enabled. How can we query this permission on profiles? Once 'API Client Whitelisting' is enabled, does the normal 'Api Enabled' permission disappear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Administrators may grant some users API access through the “API Enabled” permission. After it’s given, this permission allows the user API access through any client (such as the Data Loader, Salesforce1, Salesforce for Outlook, or the Force.com Migration Tool). **For finer control over which applications the user can use for API access, you can implement API Client Whitelisting**. This feature leverages the existing authorization capabilities of connected apps.

With API Client Whitelisting, an administrator can approve or block individual client application access for each associated connected app. All client applications that are not configured as connected apps are denied access. If you are not using connected apps, you can relax this restriction for individual users by assigning them a profile or permission set with “Use Any API Client” enabled

Help Article: [Control Individual API Client Access to Your Salesforce Org](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_control_client_access.htm)

Release Notes: [Control Individual API Client Access to Your Salesforce Organization](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_api_control.htm)